# Deep copy helper leads to index out of bounds

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, deep-copy

I have a dictionary with object as a value `Dictionary<String, Object>`. Using **Deep copy** I am creating a clone of the dictionary. Adding the clone to a variable, for each key I am adding `key + "String"`, as a column in a data table that contains same number and values of columns as key in dictionary. Adding this updated `dictionary[key]` to list and adding the list to the data table.

This process is working fine but sometimes it lead to

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

and

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

Can anyone help me with this and let me know the reason of occasionally getting this error.

```
Dictionary<String, Object> obj=
    DeepCopyHelper.Clone(taskResult.TaskStatistics.TaskSpecificData.StatisticsData());
var taskSpecificRefData = new Dictionary<String, Object>(obj);
foreach (String key in taskSpecificRefData.Keys)
{
    if (!dtReturn.Columns.Contains(key + "Ref"))
    {
        dtReturn.Columns.Add(key + "Ref");
        dataRowObjects.Add(taskSpecificRefData[key]);
    }
}
dtReturn.Rows.Add(dataRowObjects.ToArray());






 public static T Clone<T>(T source)
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
            }
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (stream)
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Rather than *describing* the code, it would be much easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi,
I have added the code, kindly view and help me with that.

Comment: Well you've added *some* (badly formatted) code... that's not the same as a [mcve] though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format code in a post.

Comment: At what lines does the errors happen? At please show the code for DeepCopyHelper as well.

Comment: Hi, @TamasIonut I have added the code of deep copy helper. The exact reason is not known.